# Bypass Jooq optimstic locking and DefaultRecordListener for some method

Tags: java, jooq

I would like to synchronize table from server A to B, the record should be exactly same from the source. It is just like manual replication work.

The method is retrieving from source record as json and insert/update to destination server to get same table records including version field.

I have a problem with updating from source to destination, I found no matter how the each fields are identical, it will update date modified and version field.

Any solution to force update those fields(version or date) without turn off optimistic locking parameter and bypass customized "DefaultRecordListener" class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.11, it is not possible to bypass setting of record version or timestamp with an out of the box feature. I have created a feature request to implement this in jOOQ 3.12: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8924

There are a few workarounds, all of which assume that you've already turned off [`Settings.executeWithOptimisticLocking`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#executeWithOptimisticLocking) in your data copying logic

#### Workaround: Using a [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordListener.html)

If you're using record versions (not timestamps), you could set the record version to `version - 1` prior to storing your record. That would lead to the version being updated again to the same value. A hack, but might be good enough.

#### Workaround: Re-generate tables for this purpose

You could re-generate all the tables involved in this operation a second time without record versions / timestamps, and use those alternative generated tables for your data copying.

#### Workaround: Don't use `UpdatableRecord`

Instead of using `UpdatableRecord`, you could write actual `INSERT` statements. Notice that you can pass any `Record` to an `INSERT` statement via the [`InsertSetStep.set(Record)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertSetStep.html#set-org.jooq.Record-) method. It will have a similar effect as calling `record.insert()`, i.e. only the changed fields will be inserted.

Comment: thank you, I'm using UpdateSetFirstStep (update) or InsertSetStep (insert) for the workaround of my problem.